# I can't find Smoke material in shader editor

Tags: materials

I have watched many tutorials and am still unable to find where it is. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or what.

Answer (score 1):

There are three shader nodes in Blender 2.80 that could be what you're searching for. None of them are called "smoke", but they can all be used to create (a part of) a smoke material. You can find them in the shader editor under *Add > Shader*.

1. [Principled Volume](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/volume_principled.html)
2. [Volume Absorption](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/volume_absorption.html)
3. [Volume Scatter](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/volume_scatter.html)

[image]

Comment: I'm talking about the actual material.

Comment: @Yohello1 What do you mean by that, can you elaborate? You have to create all materials from scratch using nodes, there are no presets for materials (unless you've installed an add-on that provides them). The only thing that creates it out of the box that is already shipped with Blender are the Quick Effects (Object > Quick Effects > Quick Smoke). This sets up the smokes simulation and material which uses the *Principled Volume* shader.

Comment: Okay I thought when I make the domain it will  automatically male the material.